# tkinter winfo_screenwidth() when used with dual monitors

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, multiple-monitors

With tkinter canvas, to calculate the size of the graphics I display, I normally use the function `winfo_screenwidth()`, and size my objects accordingly.
But when used on a system with two monitors, `winfo_screenwidth()` returns the combined width of both monitors -- which messes up my graphics.
How can I find out the screen width in pixels of each monitor, separately?

I have had this problem with several versions of Python 3.x and several versions of tkinter (all 8.5 or above) on a variety of Linux machines (Ubuntu and Mint).

For example, the first monitor is 1440 pixels wide. The second is 1980 pixels wide. `winfo_screenwidth()` returns 3360.

I need to find a way to determine the screenwidth for each monitor independently.

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17741928/python-tkinter-screen-width-and-height-secondary-display) I think.

Comment: @IronManMark20 it isn't. They are two related, but different issues.

Comment: Ran into this exact problem see:
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24377988/tkinter-on-ubuntu-14-02-reports-width-as-sum-of-both-monitors>

Answer (score 8):

It is an old question, but still: for a cross-platform solution, you could try the [screeninfo](https://pypi.org/project/screeninfo/) module, and get information about every monitor with:

```
import screeninfo
screeninfo.get_monitors()
```

If you need to know on which monitor one of your windows is located, you could use:

```
def get_monitor_from_coord(x, y):
    monitors = screeninfo.get_monitors()

    for m in reversed(monitors):
        if m.x <= x <= m.width + m.x and m.y <= y <= m.height + m.y:
            return m
    return monitors[0]

# Get the screen which contains top
current_screen = get_monitor_from_coord(top.winfo_x(), top.winfo_y())

# Get the monitor's size
print current_screen.width, current_screen.height
```

(where top is your Tk root)

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this slightly different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17741928/python-tkinter-screen-width-and-height-secondary-display), I would suggest the following:

```
 t.state('zoomed')
 m_1_height= t.winfo_height()
 m_1_width= t.winfo_width() #this is the width you need for monitor 1
```

That way the window will zoom to fill one screen. The other monitor's width is just `wininfo_screenwidth()-m_1_width`

I also would point you to the excellent ctypes method of finding monitor sizes for windows found [here](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/460509-get-the-actual-and-usable-sizes-of-all-the-monitor/). NOTE: unlike the post says, ctypes is in stdlib! No need to install anything.