# Tkinter window jumps to primary screen when launched from secondary screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am using my PC as primary screen + 1 more monitor as secondary screen.

Whenever I launch my tkinter application from secondary display, root window always opens in the primary display.

Is there any way to keep the root window on the secondary display from where application is executed ?

I have searched SO and Tkinter documentation but couldn't find the answer.

Comment: `tkinter.Tk` has a attribute called `geometry()`.Have you tried it?

Comment: win32api as a GetMonitorInfo method, this may be useful http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32api__GetMonitorInfo_meth.html

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA How to change display with geometry ?

Comment: @EricMathieu I am aware of this. How do I set the window to launch on secondary monitor ?

Comment: If you want to make effect on your PC.you could manually set the offset to do that.If not, you may need to refer Eric's suggestion.

Comment: @tan_an I cannot confirm by testing right now but setting the x value in the geometry to your_first_monitor_width + x should do the trick

Comment: @tan_an you can also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30312875/tkinter-winfo-screenwidth-when-used-with-dual-monitors (maybe you already did)

Comment: @EricMathieu thanks. i will give it a try